# Does the convolution $q(t) = q'(t)\circledast\theta(t)$ always holds? Why?, if not, What is needed?

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, convolution, signal-processing

Does the convolution $q(t) = q'(t)\circledast\theta(t)$ always holds? Why?, if not, What is needed?

$\theta(t)$ is the standard unitary step function. I want to know which characteristics has to have $q(t)$ to make $q(t) = q'(t)\circledast\theta(t)$ true... and if true, try to understand why it is so, and if it can be think of the derivatives as the step-response-function of LIT systems (Linear and Time-Invariant).

Comment: In general, it's true : in the sense of distributions $q=q\star \delta=q \star \theta'=q' \star \theta$, due to rule $(f \star g)'=f' \star g = f \star g'$

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for your comment. Actually that is what I use to found the equality, but I am not really sure if is valid for every function, because of the use of distributions (as the $\delta$), which have more complicated meanings and treatment, formally speaking. PS: for the convolution operator you can use \circledast $\circledast$, the star sign, at least in signals processing, is reserved to the autocorrelation operator, which differs in one sign compared with the convolution.

Comment: I don't think that there are much exceptions even in the distribution sense. Besides, for the notational conventions, I am aware of notations in signal processing, but on the mathematical side you see mainly a six branches star (without circle around) whereas the five branches star is found mainly in older books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the bilateral Laplace transform we have

$$
Q(s) = (s Q(s))\frac 1s
$$

so

$$
Q(s)=Q(s)
$$

which is true for all $|q(t)|\le M e^{\alpha t}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I didn´t think before in using the Laplace transform. But I think in your answer there is a subtle mistake: you are using the "unilateral Laplace transform" which is defined from zero to infinity, when the convolution integral starts from -infinity to infinity, that is why you kept a $q(0)$ term... if instead the "bilateral Laplace transform" is used, which goes to $\pm$infinity, the differentiation part becomes $\mathbb{L}\{\dot{x}\} = sX(s)$, leading to the equality... if you want to improve your answer I can accept it as this question answer.

Comment: You are right. I forgot the limits concerning the convolution operation. Thanks.